# css-grid div not resizing when used in react component

Tags: html, css, reactjs, responsive-design, css-grid

I have made a css grid layout in a sample portfolio page i have made, when i did it with just html / css it worked fine and was responsive: The code is here:
https://codepen.io/abhinavthinktank/full/YevQNq/

The one which isn't responsive is hosted here:
https://abhinav-m.github.io/

The react components for the same are here: https://github.com/abhinav-m/personal-portfolio/tree/master/src/components

I made the same using react, sass and node, however this one is not responsive, to be exact the `div` with the class `techStack` is not resizing.
Here's the grid layout css:

```
.gridContainer {
 display: grid;
 grid-template-rows: 15px 10% 20% 10% 20% 20% 20% 25px;
 grid-template-columns: 10% 80% 10%;
 grid-row-gap: 25px;
 justify-items: center; }
```

and the `div class='techStack'` css:

```
.techStack {
 grid-row: 6 / 7;
 grid-column: 2 / 3;
 background: bisque; }
```

The CSS of both of these appear to be the same! I can't understand why one of these is not working.

LINK FOR JSFIDDLE : https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/121098/ (not responsive)

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D I checked out that question, and ran my code through an html validator, I will try to setup a fiddle soon and post it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image icons (`.dev-icon-* colored`) are a list of inline-level `::before` pseudo-elements, which are each contained inside an inline-level `i` element, which are all contained inside a block-level `div` element.

The icons are provided by a third party service ([devicon](http://konpa.github.io/devicon/)).

For whatever reason, these pseudo-elements, *as devicon icons*, don't wrap.

However, if you switch out the devicon code (e.g. `content: "\e845"`) with plain text (e.g. `content: "text text text text"`), then the pseudo-elements do wrap.

Alternatively, if you switch the `div` container from `display: block` (the default) to `display: flex`, the devicons wrap, as well.

So the problem seems to boil down to devicons in a block container.

Here's a simple overall solution:

```
div.icons {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for giving such a detailed answer! , The problem is , the same code ( as far as i have compared, is working here:https://codepen.io/abhinavthinktank/full/YevQNq/). This caused me alot of confusion to where i was going wrong.

Comment: Only difference is, im using native html and css in the codepen link with css grid. The second one is a bundle.js file built using webpack (from a bunch of react components), however the generated html/css is practically the same.

Comment: Agreed. It's a bit of mystery. There's a lot of third-party code in play here. Somewhere in that heavy mix there is a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

I had a look but I can't work out what the cause of the difference is. I'm guessing it's a style somewhere else on the page or because of a slightly different structuring of elements.

However, if you set the style of your icons to `display: inline-block` then it fixes your problem.

Comment: Thank you, that does fix the problem. Im still not sure what is causing the problem though, not sure how to find out.